# Mean value on a grouped boxplots in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I want to create grouped boxplots out of my data:

```
X     variable value
Cat1  Var1     10
Cat2  Var1     8
Cat3  Var1     7
Cat4  Var1     15
Cat1  Var2     4
Cat2  Var2     3
Cat3  Var2     4
Cat4  Var2     1
```

I was able to retrieve it with:

```
ggplot() +
    geom_boxplot(aes(x=dataFiltered$X, y=dataFiltered$value, color=dataFiltered$variable))+
    ylim(c(-5, 15))
```

Right now I want to add additional points which will show average(mean) for each boxplot. I tried:

```
ggplot() +
    geom_boxplot(aes(x=dataFiltered$X, y=dataFiltered$value, color=dataFiltered$variable))+
    ylim(c(-5, 15))+
    geom_point(stat="identity", aes(x=means$`dataFiltered$X`, y=means$`dataFiltered$value`), col = "red",pch=18)
```

but it shows 4 values at the same X position (red dots in picture below)[image]

I tried to use facet_wrap but I am not able to correct an error:

```
ggplot() +
    geom_boxplot(aes(x=dataFiltered$X, y=dataFiltered$value, color=dataFiltered$variable))+
    ylim(c(-5, 15))+
    geom_point(stat="identity", aes(x=means$`dataFiltered$X`, y=means$`dataFiltered$value`), col = "red",pch=18) +
    facet_wrap(~means$`dataFiltered$variable`, scales='free')

Error in layout_base... At least one layer must contain all variables used for facetting.
```

Is there a way to put a mean value on a grouped boxplots?

Comment: never use `data$colvar` in aesthetic. Use just the name of the variable (e.g.: `aes(x = X, y = value, color = variable`) and the data arg.

Comment: ok, thx for the info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add a `stat_summary()` call:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
df <- bind_rows(lapply(c(
  "Cat1  Var1     10",
  "Cat2  Var1     8",
  "Cat3  Var1     7",
  "Cat4  Var1     15",
  "Cat1  Var2     4",
  "Cat2  Var2     3",
  "Cat3  Var2     4",
  "Cat4  Var2     1"), data.frame))
colnames(df) <- "V1"
df2 <- df %>%
        separate(V1, c("X", "variable", "value"), sep="\\s+") %>%
        mutate(value = as.integer(value))

ggplot(df2, aes(x=X, y=value, color=variable)) +
        geom_boxplot()+
        ylim(c(-5, 15)) + 
        stat_summary(geom = "point", fun.y = "mean", colour = "red", size = 4)
```

If you want it for each group, try this:

```
ggplot(df2, aes(x=X, y=value, color=variable)) +
        geom_boxplot()+
        ylim(c(-5, 15)) +
        stat_summary(geom = "point", aes(group=variable, col=variable), 
            fun.y = "mean", size = 4, position=position_dodge(width=0.5))
```

When there are small sample sizes, these plots can be misleading.

Comment: Unfortunately, stat_summary shows only 1 mean per each group. I would like to have a value per each pair X(Cat)-variable(Var).